# Trying to retrieve all users of a role

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve all of the users of a given role to display to display to users in another role.

i.e. users in role SuperAdmin get a screen with a list of all users in role BaseUser.

I tried

```
var query = (new Parse.Query(Parse.Role));
query.equalTo("name", "BaseUser");
query.include("users")
query.find({ success: function(role) {
  console.log(role)
}})
```

This just gives me a 400 bad request.

I also tried

```
var query = (new Parse.Query(Parse.Role));
query.equalTo("name", "BaseUser");
query.find({ success: function(role) {
  query = (new Parse.Query(Parse.User));
  query.equalTo("role",role)
  query.find({success: function(users) {
    console.log(users)
  }})
}})
```

Similarly I get a 400 bad request.  Any advice?

*Updated*

```
var query = (new Parse.Query(Parse.Role));
query.equalTo("name", "SuperAdmin");
query.first({ success: function(role) {
  query = (new Parse.Query(Parse.User));
  query.equalTo("role",role)
  query.find({success: function(users) {
    console.log(users)
  },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }})
}})
```

I changed the top (outer) query from find to first, as it was an array not one element and I in fact only need the 1 matching role back.  Now I get back an empty array not an error.  Still  not my users though

*Updated*

Figured it out

```
var query = (new Parse.Query(Parse.Role));
query.equalTo("name", "SuperAdmin");
query.first({ success: function(role) {
  role.relation('users').query().find({success: function(users) {
     console.log(users)
  }})
}})
```

This will pull in the users relation and allow you to query on it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#general-responses), an error code of 400 will still include a response with an error. In your case, you haven't included a `error:` callback. Change your query to look like:

```
query.find({
    success: function(users) {
        console.log(users);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

So you can see what the actual error is.

Comment: Great point.
t.Error {code: 102, message: "find field [{"__type"=>"Pointer", "className"=>"_R…"objectId"=>"VQaWK0DEKR"}] has invalid type Array"}

So I altered my query as seen in my edit.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out. Good practice to always put in the error block, you never know what might happen!